# Change value in character pointers results in blank or question mark

Tags: c, pointers, character

I am trying to learn about C programming. At the moment I am trying to understand variables of different character types. Eg: char var VS char* var VS const char var VS const* char var, etc. This is the code I came up with:

```
char* char_A[2] = {'A'};
const char* char_AA[2] = {'AA'};
char* const char_AAA[50] = {'AAA'};
const char* const char_AAAA[50] = {'AAAA'};

printf("\n\n"
       "char_A: %c\n"
       "char_AA: %c\n"
       "char_AAA: %c\n"
       "char_AAAA: %c\n"
       " \n\n"
       , char_A, char_AA, char_AAA, char_AAAA);

char_A[0] = 'B';
char_AA[0] = 'CD';
// char_AAA = 'Changed char_AAA'; // ILLEGAL, reason: constant content, movable pointer
// char_AAAA = 'Changed char_AAAA'; // ILLEGAL, reason: constant content and pointer!

printf("\n\n"
       "char_A: %c\n"
       "char_AA: %c\n"
       "char_AAA: %c\n"
       "char_AAAA: %c\n"
       " \n\n"
        , char_A, char_AA, char_AAA, char_AAAA);

//*char_AAA = char_A; // allowed because only the content cannot be changed (does not work with char array but works with other format, I believe)
// *char_AAAA = &char_AA; // ILLEGAL, reason: constant content and pointer!


printf("\n\n"
       "char_A: %c\n"
       "char_AA: %c\n"
       "char_AAA: %c\n"
       "char_AAAA: %c\n"
       " \n\n"
        , char_A, char_AA, char_AAA, char_AAAA);
```

why do I get the following output?:

```
char_A: 
char_AA: �
char_AAA: P
char_AAAA: �




char_A: 
char_AA: �
char_AAA: P
char_AAAA: �




char_A: 
char_AA: �
char_AAA: P
char_AAAA: �
```

I previously defined my char variables in the following way: `char* char_A = 'A';` but too did not result in my expected output. I was unable to change the values of the char variables so I tried char arrays instead, which as you can see did not go as I planned...

tl;dr why do I get this weird output, why will my char variables not change as I want them to?

Edit: I am using CLion to compile my program, it uses CMake to compile. There are no errors and it runs well. HOWEVER, when I compile the program with gcc I get errors, as the comments are pointing out. Anyone care to illustrate how all of these types differ? I can only find tutorials and answers comparing two and maybe three of them, but not all of them. I have put this little infographic together that I got from multiple websites:

char* vs const char* vs char* const vs const char* const

- char* means that both the pointer and the contents (character/string) can be changed
- const char* means that the pointer can be changed but the content cannot
- char* const means that the pointer cannot be changed but the content can
- const char* const means that both the pointer AND the content CANNOT be changed

Comment: `char*` is a pointer type, not a character type. It is a pointer to a character, you need to learn about pointers, not characters

Comment: The reason you see `char*` so often in C is so you can have strings, ie sequences of characters in memory. The idea of `char*` is to point to memory which contains one or more characters

Comment: Your compiler should be complaining about converting integers to pointers and probably about multi character literals too.  The variable definitions should probably be using double quotes, not single quotes. Or you should be removing `*` from at least some of the definitions.  I’ve not reviewed the printing; it’s likely there are problems there too.  Heed your compiler. If it isn’t warning, turn the warnings on, or get a better compiler.

Comment: But none of those types are actually `char`, they are all arrays of pointers to `char`. When you try to print them with `%c`, you are printing the address of the array that contains your pointers as if it is a `char`. When you interpret those values as `char` it so happens that most of them are non printable

Comment: @pointersarehard C is a difficult language, and Stack Overflow is not a tutoring website. You should find yourself a *beginner text book* and then reading it you can make somewhat sensible questions.

Comment: Antti is one of the respected members of this site. They have been helping beginners and experts for several years. I recommend that you take their suggestion seriously and get a good book. Writing bits of code when you do not know the basics and then asking for explanations of why it does what it does is a poor use of your time and of the people on this site.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, nothing wrong with writing a program of your own to better understand what you are doing. Generally something to be encouraged. Though, in this case the understanding is clearly lagging too far behind for it to be a useful exercise.

Comment: @Graeme I agree with you for when you know enough to write some code that will help you understand. But in this case the OPs comment (now deleted) seemed to merit some response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Anyone care to illustrate how all of these types differ?" Ok, fine, there is a lot to cover here which is why nobody has answered already.

```
// This is a char, you can initialise it with _one_ letter in single quotes
char c = 'a';

// We are allowed to change this char
c = 'b';

// This char is const, so we are not allowed to change it
const char const_c = 'c';

const_c = 'd';    // Compiler error

// This is a pointer to a char, it holds an address
// Initialise it to the address of c
char *p_char = &c;

// We can change c via p_char
*p_char = 'e';

// We can't point to const_c though
p_char = &const_c;     // Compiler error

// We need a const char * for that
const char *p_const_char = &const_c;

// Here, the const can come before or after the char, it means the same thing
char const *p_const_char2 = &const_c;

// Either way we can't change the original char via these pointers
*p_const_char = 'f';      // Compiler error
*p_const_char2 = 'g';     // Compiler error

// We can still point to a char that isn't const
p_const_char = &c;

// But are still not allowed to change it via the pointer
*p_const_char = 'h';      // Compiler error

// With printf you use %c to print a single char
printf("%c %c %c %c", c, const_c, *p_char, *p_const_char);


// You can also put chars in an array
char array[3] = { 'i', 'j', 'k' };
printf("%c %c %c", array[0], array[1], array[2]);

// We can also use pointer syntax to access the array
printf("%c %c %c", *array, *(array+1), *(array+2));

// If the array is null terminated, it contains what is known as a string in C
char string[4] = { 'i', 'j', 'k', '\0' };

// Now we can use functions from string.h, strlen give the string length
printf("%uz", strlen(string));

// Use %s to print a string with printf
printf("%s", string);

// Char arrays can be initialised with string literals which use double quotes
// The \0 is added automatically
char string2[4] = "lmn";

// But be careful, the \0 won't get added if there is not enough space
char string3[3] = "opq";

// So now strlen doesn't know when to stop, this is bad
printf("%uz", strlen(string3));

// Usually better to not specify a size and let the compiler work it out
char string4[] = "rst";

// We can point to a string literal on it's own without an array
// Technically the string literal itself should be const, so we need a const
// pointer. Although lot of compilers are lax here
const char *p_const_string = "uvw";

char *p_string = "xyz";    // Might be allowed, really shouldn't though

// Are allowed to point to something that isn't const
p_string = string4;

// We can increment the pointer to point to the next character in the string
++p_const_string;
printf("%c", *p_const_string);   // prints v

// This generally more convenient than indexes when looping over a string
while('\0' != *p_string)
    printf("%c", *p_string++);

// But if we put a const after the *, we are not allowed to change the pointer
char *const const_p_string = string4;

++const_p_string;    // Compiler error

// If we put the const in both places, we can't change what we point to
// nor the pointer itself
const char *const const_p_const_string = string4;

++const_p_const_string;        // Compiler error
*const_p_const_string = 'a';   // Compiler error
```

Think that covers most of it. Be careful about the differences between a string and a sequence of characters. The same types are used for both and the may be located in a char array (or somewhere else in memory that is not actually part of an array). The only difference is the `\0` at the end, if it doesn't have it and you treat it like a string, your program will probably crash.